# Custom fields of leads are not mapping in Account ,Opportunity and contact

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-conversion

```
public class LeadConversionTriggerHandler {
public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Lead> newLeads) {
    List<Lead> leadsToConvert = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead lead : newLeads) {
        if (lead.Flag__c) {
            leadsToConvert.add(lead);
        }
    }

    if (!leadsToConvert.isEmpty()) {
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

        for (Lead lead : leadsToConvert) {
            Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            leadConvert.setLeadId(lead.Id);
            leadConvert.setConvertedStatus('Convert');
            leadConverts.add(leadConvert);
        }

        try {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> convertResults = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);

            for (Database.LeadConvertResult convertResult : convertResults) {
                if (convertResult.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Lead ' + convertResult.getLeadId() + ' is successfully converted');
                } else {
                    throw new DmlException('Lead conversion failed. Please resolve the error and try again.');
                }
            }
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.debug('Lead conversion error: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static void handleAfterUpdate(List<Lead> updatedLeads, Map<Id, Lead> oldLeadsMap) {
    List<Lead> leadsToConvert = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead updatedLead : updatedLeads) {
        Lead oldLead = oldLeadsMap.get(updatedLead.Id);
        System.debug('oldLead'+oldLead);
         System.debug('updatedLead'+updatedLead);

        if (updatedLead.Flag__c && !oldLead.Flag__c) {
            leadsToConvert.add(updatedLead);
            System.debug('leadsToConvert'+leadsToConvert);
        }
    }

    if (!leadsToConvert.isEmpty()) {
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        System.debug('leadsToConvert'+leadsToConvert);

        for (Lead leadToConvert : leadsToConvert) {
            Database.LeadConvert leadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            leadConvert.setLeadId(leadToConvert.Id);
            leadConvert.setConvertedStatus('Convert');
            leadConverts.add(leadConvert);
            
            
          
        }
        
        try {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> convertResults = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);

            for (Database.LeadConvertResult convertResult : convertResults) {
                if (convertResult.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Lead ' + convertResult.getLeadId() + ' is successfully converted');
                } else {
                    System.debug('Lead conversion failed for LeadId: ' + convertResult.getLeadId());
                }
            }
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.debug('Lead conversion error: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When sales reps convert qualified leads, the information from the standard lead fields appears in `standard fields for contact, account, and opportunity records`. If you set up custom lead fields, you specify how that custom information converts to `custom fields in accounts, contacts, and opportunities`.

- From the `object management settings for leads`, go to the `fields section`, then click `Map Lead Fields`.
- For each custom lead field, choose a custom account, contact, or opportunity field into which you want the information inserted when you convert a lead. In Lightning Experience, a custom lead field can map to account, contact, and opportunity fields at the same time.
- Save your work.

As per the documentation, The following Lead custom field types can only be mapped to custom fields of the same data type.

- Checkbox
- Currency
- Date
- Date/Time
- Email
- Geolocation
- Encrypted (Classic)
- Number
- Percent
- Phone
- Multi-select Picklist
- Long Text
- Rich Text
- URL

[Guidelines for Mapping Custom Lead Fields for Lead Conversion](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_mapleads_guidelines.htm&type=5)

[Lead Conversion Field Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lead_conversion_mapping.htm&type=5)

**Standard and Custom Lead Fields:**

- The system automatically maps standard lead fields to the standard account, contact, and opportunity fields.
- For custom lead fields, your administrator can specify how they map to custom account, contact, and opportunity fields.
- The system assigns the default picklist values for the account, contact, and opportunity when mapping standard lead picklist fields that are blank. If your organization uses record types, blank values are replaced with the default picklist values of the new record owner.

Check out the [Considerations for Converting Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.leads_notes.htm&type=5)

Comment: Mapping is already there but the values are not populating
@Tushar Jadav

Comment: @user131546 Considerations for Converting Leads:

When updating existing accounts or contacts during lead conversion, the values of mapped lead fields do not overwrite the values of the mapped account and contact fields.